# Want Square Waves based on Injection Timing of 4-Stroke Engine

Tags: signal, power-electronics, inverter, waveform, rpm

Recently, I am working on ECU of CNG Auto Rickshaw having 4 Stroke Engine.

Here, Image shows the Engine of Auto Rickshaw.[image: Engine of Auto Rickshaw.]

I have already taken reading of MAP, TPS and RPM. And now I am working on Injection Timing.
For that, I am taking signals from RPM socket(As I don't know which sensor it is).

Here, In Image there is RPM Socket from which I am taking Signals by connecting probe of Oscilloscope to Yellow Wire.[image: RPM Socket]

And I am getting Signal like given in this Image,[image: RPM Signals]

Now, I want signals as showed in below Image,[image: Desired Output Signals]

I have tried getting this signal using LOW PASS FILTER followed by SCHMITT TRIGGER and getting this kind of result,[image: Using LOW PASS FILTER and SCHMITT TRIGGER]

So, I need help in getting proper square wave signal.....

Circuit that I have implemented....

1) Schmitt Trigger

[image: Schmitt Trigger]

2)Low Pass Filter
[image: Low Pass Filter]

Comment: so, are you looking for waveform in white color to be produced using the yellowish waveform? can you share the low pas filter and schmitt trigger section you have implemented?

Comment: A comparator and a reference?

Comment: Yes...Attaching in Question...@Umar

Comment: I don't get you...@winny

Comment: Wrong ref for V- to Op Amp. It should be 2~3V.

Comment: Use your existing comparator but tie the input to minus instead and use a divider from some reference, say VCC to plus. Keep your existing low pass filter. This way you will get your signal inversion too which you need according to your drawn waveform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes me 20x as long to explain this as it would for me to design it.

> The optimal design should minimize latency with adequate noise resonance filtering , i.e. matched filter with maximum signal to noise ratio.

- My timing analysis indicates your pulse has a resonance in the 3.75kHz region and the pulse interval is 32ms (31Hz) or 1875 RPM ( if 1/rev, 938 RPM if 2/rev).
- Tolerance to latency of 1 deg at 6000 RPM is equivalent to 28 us which needs to be accounted for in filter ignition timing vs RPM. A **28us = T for low pass filter,** LPF (maximum. )

  - if 1 pulse/rev then 100Hz = 6000 RPM = 10ms interval
- Alternative to a LPF filter is a non-retriggerable one shot with much like a scope trigger with a dwell of 6 cycles @3.75kHz unless there are conditions that exceed this. **Thus 6/3.75kHz= 1.6ms**
- The signal is the negative edge from +22V for the leading edge of the Hall sensor while there is resonant noise on the trailing edge of the sensor after a period of reaching +22V.

  - There is some DC dwell to be ignored after the sensor's leading active low pulse and the trailing active high sense positive pulse.
- **The ideal threshold appears to be in the 2 to 4V range for hysteresis thresholds.**

  - it is worthy to note that the positive feedback ratio defines the threshold and hysteresis as a function of the output swing with respect to the Reference level for a a differential amp. So ground is a poor choice of reference. It should be ~ V/2  or if 2,4V thresholds desired then V- =(2+4)/2 = 3V ( not ground )

**Design Recommendation**

> Confirm signal, noise range and sensor if 1 or 2 pulse per rev and max RPM.

- Stage 1: a 28us LPF  with Rseries 100k with shunt of C= 28us/100k = 280 pF  max.
- Stage 2: 5V 74HC14 Schmitt trigger using Vcc=5V with hystereis thresholds of Vcc/3, 2Vcc/3
- Stage 3 rising edge 1 shot of 1.6ms with feedback to make non-retriggerable to disable input using. 74HC123

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fotlCS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

100K current limits to 0.22mA satisfies the max 5mA internal ESD clamp diode specs. Latency of 28us needs to checked for max RPM.  One shot syncs to leading negative edge and filters out trailing edge glitch at all RPM. ( T=1.6ms needs to be increased to satisfy minimum RPM)